# Reference list from subsite

Tags: custom-list, external-content-type, sub-site

I want to use a list found in a parent site as a lookup in a list.

As far as I could find was using external content types, however I don't know what the sql server back-end address is or what the table would be called that represents the list.

In the end-game, I want to use one column from the parent-site list as a `lookup` and then when I perform a workflow based on the subsite list. I want to send an e-mail to that look-up columns associated person.

Is there some way I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to lookup column in sub site which source list from parent site?

Comment: Yes, I almost want a 2-column "site column" kind of functionality.